# Инициализация устройства в Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Всем привет , есть такая команда :

```
echo "lm96163 0x4c" > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-4/new_device
```

Я знаю ,что этой командой мы включаем температурный датчик , но не совсем понимаю , как это происходит программно.

---

Я предположил ,что это происходит так , мы загружаем модуль с драйвером (lm96163) по адресу устройства (0x4c) ,тем самым мы инициализируем устройство и делаем его доступным для работы. Верно ли я понял?

---

И еще такой вопрос ,что за файл new_device , я его везде встречаю в подобных командах , примерно понимаю для чего он , но не понимаю ,как он работает.

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/instantiating-devices  См. метод 4

Comment: @Mike ,спасибо=)